# Different Colors of Status Bar in each Activity

Tags: android, statusbar

Is it possible to have different color of status bar in each Activity like in **Activity A** is *blue*, **Activity B** is *red*, and **Activity C** is *green*?

Comment: Either you can create style for every activity and assign the styles to the activities in Manifest.xml or you can just simply change the Status bar color programmatically in `onCreate()` of every Activity. Questions like these have already been asked many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your Activities `onCreate()` method to change the status bar color of the activity:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(<your color>);
```